# Undefined reference to boost::system::generic_category() in Qt project

Tags: c++, qt, boost

I am trying to link the latest boost libary (1.60) to my Qt project.
Unfortunately it always shows "C++ Boost: undefined reference to boost::system::generic_category()". Unfortunately all the solutions on the other forum posts do not work. Heres my linked directories.

```
INCLUDEPATH += C:/Qt/Qt5.5.1/boost/
LIBS += -LC:/boost/libs/ -lboost_filesystem -lboost_exception
```

I am planning on using asio.

Comment: You have `-lboost_filesystem` on your include path. Shouldn't it be in your linker param string?

Answer (score 1):

You need to link the boost system library as well: `-lboost_system`.

Answer (score 0):

if your lib and include path are correct, it should be

```
INCLUDEPATH += C:/Qt/Qt5.5.1/boost
LIBS += -LC:/boost/stage/lib -lboost_filesystem -lboost_exception
```

boost libs might have build suffix like: `boost_filesystem-mgw48-mt-s-1_60`

check you lib folder and change it to yours.

```
LIBS += -LC:/boost/stage/lib \
        -lboost_filesystem-mgw48-mt-s-1_60 \
        -lboost_exception-mgw48-mt-s-1_60
```